# How to perform a JavaScript click action based on a php session variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a page divided into tabs, each tab with a specific form. When I submit for example form2 in tab2, the controller (after treatments) takes me to tab1 (first one) on the same page, but not the same tab. I would like to be redirected to the same tab. My idea is to perform a click action to make tab2 show up (using aria-expanded="true" for tab2 and aria-expanded="false" to tab1) instead of tab1 directly after redirection.

Hope it's clear, thanks.

```
<li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into? You've not shown us any session variables and this question is not clear at all.

Comment: Also important to know what tab library you are using and how it is initialized

Comment: make a hidden field like <input type="hidden" name="tabname" value="tab2"> you will get in post method and redirect it using field value.

Answer (score 0):

on form submit, you will get to know which form is submitted among the tabs.
and in each li, you can check for the condition before giving class="active". Like this

Suppose in each for i have a hidden field by name hidd, in form1 hidd = 1, form2 hidd = 2, form3 hidd = 3;

Either you can store the value in session r a variable,

```
<li <?php if($hidd == 1) echo "class='active'"; ?>
    <a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a>
</li>
<li <?php if($hidd == 2) echo "class='active'"; ?>
    <a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a>
</li>
<li <?php if($hidd == 3) echo "class='active'"; ?>
    <a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a>
</li>
```

Comment: $hidd can be value from session or, set $hidd = input post value

Comment: yes, but the prob is there is a javascript function that put aria-expanded="true"  : `<li class="active"><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab_2"  aria-expanded="true"  >tab2</a></li>` when  we click on it and others tab got aria-expanded="false"